# Elasticsearch mapping, indexing, and querying for Autocomplete for typed phrases

Tags: node.js, elasticsearch, autocomplete, postman, n-gram

this is what my ES data looks like :

```
"boqList" : [ 
        {
            "particulars" : "Excavation ",
            "quantity" : 1500,
            "unit" : "m3",
            "rate" : 500,
            "amount" : 750000
        }, 
        {

            "particulars" : "Providing & laying Rubble Soling",
            "quantity" : 300,
            "unit" : "m2",
            "rate" : 450,
            "amount" : 135000
        }, 
        {

            "particulars" : "Providing & laying PCC M10",
            "quantity" : 30,
            "unit" : "m2",
            "rate" : 650,
            "amount" : 19500
        }, 
        {

            "particulars" : "Providing & Laying Reinforcement With Cutting, Bending & Binding With Binding Wire Etc Complete.",
            "quantity" : 50,
            "unit" : "M.T.",
            "rate" : 80000,
            "amount" : 4000000
        }, 
        {

            "particulars" : "Providing & Making Double Scaffolding",
            "quantity" : 350,
            "unit" : "m2",
            "rate" : 150,
            "amount" : 52500
        }, 

       ...
```

My NodeJS code to index and map the data looks something like this :

```
client.indices.create({
            index: "boqs",

            body: {

            settings: {
                index: {
                    analysis: {
                    filter: {},

                    analyzer: {


                    edge_ngram_analyzer: {
                    filter: ["lowercase"],
                    tokenizer: "edge_ngram_tokenizer"
                    },

                    edge_ngram_search_analyzer: {
                    tokenizer: "lowercase"
                    }

                    },

                    tokenizer: {
                        edge_ngram_tokenizer: {

                        type: "edge_ngram",
                        min_gram: 2,
                        max_gram: 5,
                        token_chars: ["letter"]

                        }
                    }


                }
                }
            },



            mappings: {


                properties: {
                boqList: {
                    properties: {
                        amount: {
                            type: "long"
                        },
                        particulars: {
                            type: "text",
                            fields: {
                                edgengram: {
                                    type: "text",
                                    analyzer: "edge_ngram_analyzer",
                                    search_analyzer: "edge_ngram_search_analyzer"
                                    }
                            },
                            analyzer: "standard"
                        },
                        quantity: {
                            type: "long"
                        },
                        rate: {
                            type: "long"
                        },
                        unit: {
                            type: "text",
                            fields: {
                                keyword: {
                                    type: "keyword",

                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                },
                projectId: {
                    type: "text",
                    fields: {
                        keyword: {
                            type: "keyword",

                        }
                    }
                }
            }



            },
            },
            }, function(err,resp,respcode){
            console.log(err,resp,respcode);
            })
```

Also I'm indexing my data like this :

```
http://localhost:9200/boqs/_doc/3
{
    "projectId" : "ABCD",
    "boqList" : [ 
       {
            "particulars" : 
            {
                "input" : ["Providing & laying Rubble Soling"]
            },
            "quantity" : 300,
            "unit" : "m2",
            "rate" : 450,
            "amount" : 135000
        }
        ]

}
```

I was trying to use the Edge NGram Approach to implement the auto complete on the 'particulars' field of my boqList and send the response as a JSON to my front end which is React.

Currently, when I try to query anything, I'm not getting any hits.

```
http://localhost:9200/boqs/_search
```

OR

```
http://localhost:9200/boqs/_search
{
  "query": {
    "multi_match": {
      "query": "Providing",  
      "type": "phrase", 
      "fields": "boqList.particulars"
    }
  }
}
```

I wanted to be able to perform auto-complete for phrases even in the middle of the 'particulars' field. 
Is there something I'm missing? I'm relatively new to Elasticsearch and so any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [the analyzed tokens produced](https://eemp.io/elasticsearch-analysis-inspector/?q=analysisReducer%7Cdefinition%7Canalyzer%7Cchar_filter%7Cfilter%7Clowercase%7Ctokenizer%7Ctype%7Cedge_ngram%7Cmin_gram%7Cmax_gram%7Ctoken_chars%7Cletter%7Ckey%7Cd6c59fdb-1ca5-4994-8483-999e101435be%7Cname%7Cedge_ngrams_analyzer%7Cdbfa71ae-39ed-4fec-959f-10ece7b3552c%7Cedge_ngrams_search_analyzer%7CsampletextReducer%7CProviding%2B%26%2Blaying%2BRubble%2BSoling%7CtokenlistReducer%5E2%7C5%5E%5E%240%7C%40%241%7C%242%7C-5%7C3%7C%40%5D%7C4%7C%405%5D%7C6%7C%247%7C8%7C9%7CM%7CA%7CN%7CB%7C%40C%5D%5D%5D%7CD%7CE%7CF%7CG%5D%7C%241%7C%242%7C-5%7C3%7C-5%7C4%7C-5%7C6%7C5%5D%7CD%7CH%7CF%7CI%5D%5D%7CJ%7CK%7CL%7C-3%5D) to see how your `edge_ngrams_analyzer` and `edge_ngrams_search_analyzer` are treating the text "Providing & laying Rubble Soling".  (disclaimer: the link is to an analysis debugging tool I created that's a WIP).  There is an inquisitor elasticsearch plugin that is likely more reliable for instances such as these.

Few additional tips:

- Your `max_gram` setting is set to only 5, which means the longest token produced for the "Providing" user search is "provi" which will not match with the search time token produced with just the `lowercase` tokenizer "providing".
- Elasticsearch has a completion suggester which might help you avoid running into  as many walls with lower level details - see the [Completion Suggester](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-suggesters.html#completion-suggester)
- Here's a comprehensive post on the topic of powering autocompletions: https://medium.com/@mourjo_sen/a-detailed-comparison-between-autocompletion-strategies-in-elasticsearch-66cb9e9c62c4 - this appears to cover your ngrams analysis approach and the suggester approach